# How to reduce the time complexity of seaching the same character in two different strings in C?

Tags: c

Input contains a

```
n
```

which indicated the total amount of the strings.
Then use scanf to scan those strings.
The task is that find out if two strings have the same characters.
If so,they are in the same group.

```
Two string belongs to same group if :

1.there exists a character that exist in both string.

2.there exists a character in both string A and B,

and there exists another character in both string B and C,

then A, B, C belong to same group.
```

for example

```
>>input
5
abbbb
a
c
ddca
fgg
```

Here "abbbb","a","c","ddca" are in the same group
and output the total numbers of groups
in this example is

```
2
```

Every characters in the strings only contains 'a'~'z'

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct str  //'ini' is used to save the initial strings  'convert' recorded the characters converted to ascii code then -'a'
{
    char ini[1001];
    int convert[1001];
} STR;
STR a[2002];

int visited[2002];// record the index that has been traverse
int count;//record the total number of groups
int record[26];//there is 26 characters from'a'~'z'


int check(int index1,int index2)
{
    int len_1=strlen(a[index1].ini);
    int len_2=strlen(a[index2].ini);
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)//reset
    {
        record[i]=0;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<len_1; i++)//traverse the first string and recorded the characters in "record"array 
    {
        record[a[index1].convert[i]]=1;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<len_2; i++)
    {
        if(record[a[index2].convert[i]]==1)//if they have same characters
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;



}
void dfs(int now,int n)//now record index ,n record the total index
{
    visited[now]=1;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(i==now) continue;
        if(visited[i]==1) continue;
        if(check(i,now))
        {
            dfs(i,n);
        }


    }

}
int main()
{

    
        int n;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%s",a[i].ini);
            int len=strlen(a[i].ini);//recording the length of the input string
            for(int j=0; j<len; j++) //convert every characters in the ini string to ascii then -'a', recording in 'convert' int array
            {
                char ch=a[i].ini[j];
                a[i].convert[j]=ch-'a';

            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)//dfs
        {
            if(visited[i]==0)
            {
                count++;
                dfs(i,n);
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",count);

    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to use DFS to search it, and use every strings as a node

Is that any better way to reduce the time complexity?

Can it be more faster?

Comment: Why do you need another array to convert to ASCII codes? That's what `char` is.

Comment: to convert a character from 'char' type to 'int 'type

Comment: @reinaqua `char` itself contains the ASCII codes, you don't need to convert it to `int`.

Comment: `i<27` should be `i<26`

Comment: @Barmar  I've corrected it .thx

Comment: @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer Oops, I mean 'convert' array to record the same character array but in its ASCII codes-'a' ASCII codes

Comment: Instead of essentially duplicating the information, you should try to make the decision whether two strings share a common leter fast. Your `record` could be part of the `STR` struct and it would save you time on long strings. If you are familiar with bitwise operations, you could store the information which of the 26 letters are present in a single 32-bit integer: a is 1, b is 2, c is 4, d is 8 and z is, let me see, 33,554,432. Then two strings `s` and `t` share a letter `if (s & t) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

- You iterate over each string 2 times (`strlen` + the for loop). That's rather inefficient.
- When done looking through the string(s), there shouldn't be a need to search for anything, if you place the results in a sensible way.
- Ideally keep track of the results from each string separately.

Something like this (naive implementation):

```
#define LETTERS 26

void str_common (const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
  bool record1 [LETTERS]={false};
  bool record2 [LETTERS]={false};
  
  for(size_t i=0; s1[i]!='\0'; i++)
  {
    record1[s1[i]-'a']=true;
  }
  
  for(size_t i=0; s2[i]!='\0'; i++)
  {
    record2[s2[i]-'a']=true;
  }
  
  for(size_t i=0; i<LETTERS; i++)
  {
    if(record1[i] && record2[i])
    {
      putchar('a' + i);
    }
  }
}
```

This is naive code because it has no error handling and also assumes that all letters in the symbol table are adjacent, which C makes no guarantees for. Still it gives something to start with.

You can rewrite this function to only work with one string at a time and instead of printing, returning the `record` array to the caller. Comparing which letters that exists in your 3 different strings then becomes trivial, just change the `if(record1[i] && record2[i])` check to contain as many strings and conditions as you need.

Comment: I see, means to use two array to record the two strings characters which have been appeared then just to compare two record array right?

Comment: @reinaqua Yes, or 3 strings or how many you need. As I wrote you can rewrite this function to only work with one string at a time, returning the result.

Comment: Thanks I have changed the check function already, now I wonder if it is possible to boost the search on DFS function?

Comment: which means my dfs is now build the edge between two strings with same characters ,is that possible to reduce the edge to boost the dfs?

Answer (score 0):

There is a place for some optimization. First, drop the `convert` arrays and replace it with `bool usedLetters[256];`. Fill it after reading each string with a simple loop over the string:

```
        scanf("%s",a[i].ini);
        for(int j=0; a[i].ini[j] != 0; j++) //scan the string till its end
        {
            unsigned char ch=a[i].ini[j];   // get a next character
            a[i].usedLetters[ch] = true;    // and note it's used
        }
```

Then checking whether two strings share a letter requires a parallel scanning of both corresponding `usedLetters[]`:

```
int check(int index1,int index2)
{
    bool *used1 = a[index1].usedLetters;
    bool *used2 = a[index2].usedLetters;

    for(int i=0; i < 256; i++)   // iterate over all possible chars
    {
        if(used1[i] && used2[i]) // char(i) used in both strings?
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, the main cost is in your scanning routine. It's not DFS (unless you consider the whole set of strings as a full graph) – for each string visited you try to compare it to *all* strings in a set, then discarding those already visited. As a result, your routine performs up to N^2 iterations of a loop and (in a worst case of all strings disjoint) up to ~(N^2)/2 calls to `check()` (it will need to identify N one-string 'groups', each time checking a starting string against N/2 other strings on average).

Comment: How to cut edges to reduce the times to call check function?

Comment: @reinaqua I have no idea. In fact, in the worst case you can't do any better than (N^2)/2 – each string verified already creates its own group and each new string needs to be checked at least against all groups found previously. This makes 1+2+...+(N-1) = O(N^2). The question I don't know the answer to is whether it can be done efficiently on average....

Comment: for example :if we know string A and string B are the same group and string B and string C are the same group, then dfs doesn't have to check or build edge between A and C, can this idea reduced the edge in dfs and reduced time complexity?